# How to remove unwanted white space

Tags: python

Using python

In my code:

```
print('Menu')
menu_items = ['pizza','burger','hotdog','salad']
menu_price = ['10','7','4','8']

print('0)',menu_items[0], '$', menu_price[0])

print('1)',menu_items[1], '$', menu_price[1])

print('2)',menu_items[2], '$', menu_price[2])

print('3)',menu_items[3], '$', menu_price[3])
```

I get:
Menu

0. pizza $ 10
1. burger $ 7
2. hotdog $ 4
3. salad $ 8

I dont want a white space between the $ and the value, how would I do this

Comment: using `,` by default separate the two string with a space inside print statement. So you can use a `+` to join 2 strings. Or you can use `f-strings` in python.

Answer (score 4):

You could use an f-string.

```
print(f"0) {menu_items[0]} ${menu_price[0]}")
```

And with a format specifier to ensure the price is printed correctly.

```
print(f"0) {menu_items[0]} ${menu_price[0]:.2f}")
```

Alternatively, you can specify the separator to `print` as being an empty string, and then manually add spaces where necessary.

```
print('0) ', menu_items[0], ' $', menu_price[0], sep='')
```

### One more thing

Structuring your data as multiple arrays works, but it's a bad design. You'd be better off keeping your related data stored together.

Rather than:

```
menu_items = ['pizza', 'burger', 'hotdog', 'salad']
menu_price = ['10', '7', '4', '8']
```

Store this as a list of tuples storing the description and price of each item.

```
menu_items = [('pizza', 10), ('burger', 7), ('hotdog', 4), ('salad', 8)]
```

Now if you want to print these with numbers, you can use enumerate and a for-loop.

```
for index, (description, price) in enumerate(menu_items):
    print(f"{index:-2d}) {description:20s} ${price:4.2f}")
```

And the result is:

```
 0) pizza                $10.00
 1) burger               $7.00
 2) hotdog               $4.00
 3) salad                $8.00
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this :)

```
print('0)', menu_items[0], '$' + str(menu_price[0]))
```

(Technically, the string conversion is not necessary in this case - since your `menu_price` array already contains strings)

Answer (score 0):

You can use this:

```
print('Menu')
menu_items = ['pizza', 'burger', 'hotdog', 'salad']
menu_price = ['10', '7', '4', '8']
[print(f"{i}) {menu[0]} ${menu[1]}") for i, menu in enumerate(zip(menu_items, menu_price))]
```

Comment: This answer would be better with some additional explanation of what it is you're showing.

Comment: It is just using the f-strings for formatting - add space where you want to and remove where it is not needed.